# I'm getting Inflate Exception and don't know why?

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, inflate-exception, invocationtargetexception

I am getting inflate exception on custom textview class which is working on other project correctly but having inflate exception in new project.

```
{ FATAL EXCEPTION: main.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.westchester.ride.driver/com.westchester.ride.driver.ActivityLogin}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class com.sgtaxi.driver.widgets.FontTextView
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class com.sgtaxi.driver.widgets.FontTextView
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:306)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1916)
                                                                           at com.westchester.ride.driver.ActivityLogin.onCreate(ActivityLogin.java:77)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5191)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773) 
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:306) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1916) 
                                                                           at com.westchester.ride.driver.ActivityLogin.onCreate(ActivityLogin.java:77) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5191) 
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773) 
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.westchester.ride.driver.R$styleable
                                                                           at com.sgtaxi.driver.widgets.FontTextView.applyAttributes(FontTextView.java:31)
                                                                           at com.sgtaxi.driver.widgets.FontTextView.<init>(FontTextView.java:22)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:306) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1916) 
                                                                           at com.westchester.ride.driver.ActivityLogin.onCreate(ActivityLogin.java:77) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5191) 
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
}
```

my fonttextview class code

```
{package com.sgtaxi.driver.widgets;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.westchester.ride.driver.R;
import com.sgtaxi.driver.utils.FontUtils;
import com.sgtaxi.driver.utils.Fonts;


public class FontTextView extends TextView {

public FontTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public FontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    applyAttributes(context, attrs);
}

public FontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    applyAttributes(context, attrs);
}

private void applyAttributes(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.FontTextView);
    String fontName = Fonts.values()   [a.getInt(R.styleable.FontTextView_fontName, 0)].getName();
    a.recycle();
    if (!isInEditMode() && !TextUtils.isEmpty(fontName)) {
        setTypeface(FontUtils.getFonts(getContext(), fontName));
    }
 }
}
```

My Activity Oncreate method in which i setContentView

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.acitivity_login);

    initializeViews();
    setlistners();

}
```

Here is my layout file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/rlMainLogin"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    android:id="@+id/ivHeaderLogin"
    layout="@layout/top_bar" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_login_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <com.sgtaxi.driver.widgets.FontTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvEnterYourLoginAndPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/login_main_heading"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:fontName="roboto_light.ttf" />

    <com.sgtaxi.driver.widgets.FontEditText
        android:id="@+id/etUserNameLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvEnterYourLoginAndPassword"
        android:background="@drawable/field_box"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_usermail"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:drawablePadding="16dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:fontName="roboto_light.ttf" />
  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my attribute file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- auto generated shit -->
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="FontTextView">
    <attr name="fontName" />
</declare-styleable>

<attr name="fontName" format="enum">
    <enum name="open_sans_regular.ttf" value="0" />
    <enum name="roboto_italic.ttf" value="1" />
    <enum name="roboto_light.ttf" value="2" />
    <enum name="roboto_light_italic.ttf" value="3" />
    <enum name="roboto_medium.ttf" value="4" />
    <enum name="roboto_medium_italic.ttf" value="5" />
    <enum name="roboto_regular.ttf" value="6" />
    <enum name="roboto_thin.ttf" value="7" />
    <enum name="roboto_thin_italic.ttf" value="8" />
    <enum name="signika_regular.ttf" value="9" />
</attr>
</resources>
```

Comment: Do you have attribute with name FontTextView declared in attrs.xml?

Comment: @AlokNair yes i have attribute file having FontTextView declared..

Comment: Is the typeface in the correct location in your project?

Comment: yes.. placed in assets/fonts..

Answer (score 0):

there was a class association error android studio doesn't recognized my widget.
i simply remove my

> com.sgtaxi.driver.widgets.FontTextView

in xml and typed again to make association.. and it worked.